# How to remember rTorrent queue after program quits

Tags: linux, rtorrent

I'm trying to make rTorrent remember its download queue when the application is closed, and continue downloads after the program is opened up again.

This tutorial has answered all of my questions but this one: [Howto: Use rtorrent like a pro « Motho ke motho ka botho](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2007/05/02/howto-use-rtorrent-like-a-pro/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting a "session" directory with the `-s` option, or with a

```
session=/path/to/directory
```

line in `.rtorrent.rc`.